# How to export one vertical column table with many rows into an excel sheet with headers on the horizontal plane?

Tags: html, css, excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to collect data. The data sent are in a word format and are all in a vertical columned table with various headers and data, alternating.

I would like to know how can I export such data from word into an excel form, with the headers filling each cell, horizontally, and the data, placed just below the headers, also in a horizontal manner.

Comment: Could you please clarify what your data looks like? I'm scratching my head a bit at your description. Also, have you tried anything? What have you tried, and how did that fail to do what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly

1. copy word table containing vertical data
2. open excel and paste it on sheet 2
3. Excel sheet 1 set formulas for data on sheet 2 for header 1 like `=sheet2!A1` for header and for data1 `=sheet2!A3` ,for header 2 `=sheet2!A2` data2 `=sheet2!A4`.

For illustration:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Congratulations on your first post (and upvote), but please take a look at the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and also remember that we dislike repetition (Your posts are always signed with avatar and name, no use repeating that). I took the liberty to improve your formatting and inline the image (as you can do once you have 15 points).